# Не отображается изображение на странице, хотя если перейти по "открыть картинку в новой вкладке" показывает изображение

Tags: html, css

```
<img class="fb-user-img" src="t1.jpg" alt="">
```

html код.

На самой странице нет изображения, хотя если открыть на новой вкладке, он показывает. Путь указан верно.

Comment: уберите класс fb-user-img и посмотрите, что будет - возможно, какие-то стили этого класса скрывают изображение

Answer (score 0):

У меня был случай что расширение adblock скрывало некоторые изображения на сайте

Comment: Да, такое бывает, если название изображение содержит какие-то стоп-слова, типа logo